# how to access from an string variable to object properties

Tags: javascript, object

hiiii im creating an application,
i get a path from url for access to object properties, and the path is string and i save in variable,
i meaning like this code,for example:

but its wrong and throw an error...any body can help me?
I'll really appreciate if someone help me. Thanks :)

```
var object = {
   music:{
      test:"",
      test2:""
   },
   video:{
      test:"",
      test2:""
   },
   pic:{
      test:"",
      test2:""
   },
   photosUsers:{
      test:"",
      test2:""
   }
}

var path = "music.test.test2";
var item = object.path
```

Comment: Your posted code will not throw an error, but `object.path` will end up being `undefined`.

Comment: I recommend to also have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html and  [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196) to get a better of how objects work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here.

First, object properties are strings, but you can't just use a dot-separated path to access a nested structure like that. At least not natively. But there are libraries for this. For example, I am the author of [dangit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dangit), which has a `namespace()` function to help you do this.

```
var item = dangit.namespace(object, 'music.test.test2');
```

Second, even if JavaScript supported a path notation like that, it would probably work like this.

```
var path = 'music.test.test2';
var item = object[path];
```

That's because `object.path` and `object[path]` are very different things, and there are important differences. Even if you have a `path` variable, `object.path` will not use it, because you are asking for a property named `path`, whereas `object[path]` gets a property named whatever the value of the `path` variable is.

Third, `object.music.test.test2` does not exist in the data structure you have provided. Use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) to learn about this.

```
console.log('music:', object.music);
console.log('music.test:', object.music.test);
```

In your example, `object.music.test` is a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). And since strings don't have a property named `test2`, trying to access it will return `undefined`.

Comment: Why do we need a library for this?  Using libraries for something that takes 4 lines of code is why we had the padLeft debacle

Comment: My `namespace()` function does a great deal more than you are imagining. Also, real world applications need many utilities, so often it makes sense to import a library not just for this, but for other functions as well. If this is somehow the only utility you need, then maybe it doesn't make sense to use a library. Use common sense. As for `left-pad` I am generally [with sindresorhus](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ama/issues/367). There are many issues at play there, and the complexity of the module doesn't affect any of them. Figure out how to trust your dependencies or keep it internal.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I would imagine that your `namespace` function does a great deal, and I wasn't trying to imply that it doesn't.  I agree with much of what sindresorhus said as well.  In this specific case, however, I'm guessing neither the rest of your library nor the full functionality of `namespace` are necessary.

Comment: No worries! That may be true. `namespace()` can help you _create_ the entire path if it doesn't exist, beyond just _read_ from it. That is more involved. For example, you have to decide whether to overwrite strings/numbers - due to their immutability - if they exist in the middle of the path. I am not sure if the OP cares about that. But dot paths are most commonly used to scaffold out a dynamically computed namespace. Once you have a reference to one, you _usually_ don't need dot paths anymore. So I am making an educated guess about what people will need, even if it is a bit out of scope. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var path_array = path.split('.');
var item = object;
for (int i = 0; i < path_array.length; i++) {
    item = item[path_array[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = {music : {test : "" , test2 : ""},video : {test : "" , test2 : ""},pic: {test : "" , test2 : ""},photosUsers: {test : "" , test2 : ""}}

//Associate the path variable to the object
object.path = "music.test.test2";
var item = object.path;
```